# is there a complete example of a deployment of several services and several camel-k integrations via argocd and kustomize

Tags: gitlab, cicd, argocd, apache-camel-k

I see here and there bits of explanation of argocd deploying applications, but I haven't seen any with camel-k yet.
a yaml application into project directory with deployment.yaml, services.yaml, ingress.yaml.
sub source directory /route/Hello.java
sub directories /dev /test /prod

the deployment.yaml is result of kamel run Hello.java -o > deployment.yaml
the process would be to push the project directory into gitlab; then go to argocd ui and make a deployment request based on the directory where application.yaml is located.
is it correct ?

thanks

Comment: ArgoCD needs manifests (yaml) files in a Git repo. I don't know Camel-K but sounds like it's generating manifests for you? Then these manifests should be stored somewhere to be read by ArgoCD.

Comment: i dont understand you. sorry.

Comment: if in my git repo i have this : \n

Comment: if in my git repo i have this : \n
/myProject

application.yaml  (into kind application for argocd)

deployement.yaml   (my route + kub kind : integration)

service.yaml (kub kind : service)

myproject/dev/kustomize.yaml  (kustomize for environnement DEV)
myproject/production/kustomize.yaml  (kustomize for environnement PORDUCTION)

i can easely only push on git, and argocd synchronize all or only manually for prod ) deploy , whern my git are updated ..the argocd work with camel-k ??

Comment: Yes. ArgoCD only cares about yaml files representing Kubernetes resources, it doesn't care if it's Camel-K or any other tech related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get some ideas from this blog post

https://camel.apache.org/blog/2023/07/camel-k-gitops/

Here you have some basic example which is configured with a configmap. You can think the same also for Services etc.

Also, your question assumes that the `kamel run` command produces a Deployment CR. This is not true. The command produces an Integration CR that is reconciled by the Camel K operator which does a series of actions before creating the related Deployment CR which is finally the one running your Camel application.